# An application of Schwarz lemma to $af(0)+bf'(0)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic and $|f(z)|\le 1$ for all $|z|\le 1$. If $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$, show that
$$|af(0)+bf'(0)| \le (|a|^2+|b|^2)^{1/2}$$

Comment: The right hand side makes no sense, did you mean to put the modulus of the sum of the squares?

Answer (score 2):

The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality yields

$$\lvert af(0) + bf'(0)\rvert^2 \leqslant \left(\lvert a\rvert^2 + \lvert b\rvert^2\right)\cdot \left(\lvert f(0)\rvert^2 + \lvert f'(0)\rvert^2\right),$$

and for suitably chosen $a,b$ we have equality. So what one needs to show is

$$\lvert f(0)\rvert^2 + \lvert f'(0)\rvert^2 \leqslant 1.$$

By the Schwarz-Pick lemma, we have

$$\frac{\lvert f'(z)\rvert}{1 - \lvert f(z)\rvert^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{1 - \lvert z\rvert^2}$$

for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$ if $f \colon \mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic, in our situation

$$\lvert f'(0)\rvert \leqslant 1 - \lvert f(0)\rvert^2 \leqslant 1 \Rightarrow \lvert f'(0)\rvert^2 \leqslant 1 - \lvert f(0)\rvert^2.$$